# Popover button not showing in split view app

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, popover

I have a split view app that should show a menu button when the device is in portrait orientation and the Master view is hidden.

When the app launches in portrait mode, this function is executed:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc {

    barButtonItem.title = @"Menu";
    self.popoverController = pc;
    self.rootPopoverButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    // Get current detail view (splitVC-->detailNavVC-->currentVC).
    UINavigationController *detailNav = [self.splitController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 1];
    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = [detailNav.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 0];
    [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem: rootPopoverButtonItem];
}
```

This function in turn launches the function in TitleViewController.m:

```
- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    // Add the popover button to the toolbar.
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [itemsArray insertObject: barButtonItem atIndex: 0];
    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];
}
```

All of this code seems to run correctly, but no menu button is showing. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved the problem by adding the following line after setting the toolbar items:

```
[self.view reloadInputViews];
```